# EF -script option

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

I ran the command

```
update-database -script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase -TargertMigration "<migration name>".
```

The console reported

```
"Applying explicit migration: <migration name>
```

Unfortunately, I don't know where the script(s) have been saved. 
I imagined these script(s) would be separate to those you already see in the Solutions Explorer.

Many thanks.

Comment: The script isn't saved anywhere, it's in the console output (stdout)!

Comment: Thanks phuzi. Are you referring to the Package Manager console? In the Package Manager Console it says "Applying explicit migration: <migration>" for the several migrations. No SQL script. Is there another console?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was talking about the command line tools for EF Core. I believe you're using the non-Core EF so the script should be generated and shown in a new editor window in VS!

Comment: Yes,that's where it was! Many thanks.